Is possible to define a typedef for complex and composite datatypes in PHP or Laravel?
Is there a way to define a special type just a placeholder for complex return data types?

Builder|Payment|Model
Can I define a typedef for this?
PaymentBuilder => Builder|Payment|Model
And return the new datatype for the methods in certain class.
Is that possible?
I am trying to create a user-defined typedef in PHP.
I expect to use this typedef in class files instead of the actual composite datatypes - to be returned for example.
I can't do this right now :(

What do you mean by "typedef"? Is this maybe a problem around static analysis with PHPStan or Psalm?

Broadly speaking PHP does not currently support this type of "type aliasing". You might be able to achieve this if Builder|Payment|Model are all interfaces, in which case you have have interface PaymentBuilder extends Builder,Payment,Model

FWIW, there's been some discussion in the community about this, with two threads here and here being some great reads. I think overall sentiment is that people are for this, at a high level, but there's some caveats that need to be solved, accounted for, and/or accepted as limitation or side effects.
